# Matrix dot product in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python and confused on a code

```
X = np.array([2,3,4,4])
print(np.dot(X,X))
```

This works

```
Y = np.array([[100],
        [200],
        [300],
        [400]])
print(np.dot(Y,Y))
```

This doesn't. I understood it is because of the relationship with array dimensions. But I cant understand how. Please explain.

Comment: You're trying to multiplicate a 4x1 with a 4x1 matrix. Try transposing the second `Y` if you want the matrix multiplication to happen, or transpose the first one if you want a scalar.

Comment: how 1*4 can be done with 1*4 ?

Comment: No, I meant effectively either have 1x4 with 4x1 for a scalar, or 4x1 with 1x4 for a matrix. So either `np.dot(Y, Y.T)` or `np.dot(Y.T,Y)`

Comment: ok. But i can't get how  1*4 and 1*4 gives a scalar result?

Comment: Read [the doc of numpy.dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), it starts by stating:  "If both a and b are 1-D arrays, it is inner product of vectors "

Comment: @HariKrishnan Basic math: If you multiply a row vector with a column vector, you get the inner product and thus a scalar. On the other hand, if you multiply a column vector with a row vector (now interpret both as nx1 matrices), you get a nxn matrix as a result.

Comment: Here in first case the multiplication is with a row vector to another row vector i,e (1*5) with (1*5).and in second case it is with column vector with another column vector ryt? please read the question properly.

Comment: `X` is not a row vector.  Its shape is (4,), not (1,4).  @ThierryLathuille is right, the special case for `1d` arrays applies.

Answer (score 0):

`X` is a 1d array (row vector is not the right descriptor):

```
In [382]: X = np.array([2,3,4,4])
In [383]: X.shape
Out[383]: (4,)
In [384]: np.dot(X,X)     # docs for 1d arrays apply
Out[384]: 45
```

`Y` is 2d array.

```
In [385]: Y = X[:,None]
In [386]: Y
Out[386]: 
array([[2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [4]])
In [387]: Y.shape
Out[387]: (4, 1)
In [388]: np.dot(Y,Y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-388-3a0bc5156893> in <module>()
----> 1 np.dot(Y,Y)

ValueError: shapes (4,1) and (4,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)
```

For 2d arrays, the last dimension of the first pairs with the 2nd to the last of second.

```
In [389]: np.dot(Y,Y.T)    # (4,1) pair with (1,4) to produce (4,4)
Out[389]: 
array([[ 4,  6,  8,  8],
       [ 6,  9, 12, 12],
       [ 8, 12, 16, 16],
       [ 8, 12, 16, 16]])
In [390]: np.dot(Y.T,Y)    # (1,4) pair with (4,1) to produce (1,1)
Out[390]: array([[45]])
```